# Hamiltonian system invariant in the unit circle but not periodic orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I consider the a nonlinear system of the following:

\begin{align}\dot x&=x^2 + 3y^2 - 1 \\ \dot y &= -2xy \end{align}

I have to demonstrate that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is an invariant set, but not periodic orbits.

My attempt is that:

1. I first note that this system is Hamiltonian so that I can find a Hamiltonian function which is of the form:
   $$
   H(x,y) = x^2 y + y^3 - y
   $$
2. I find that: if $(x,y) \in C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} | x^2 + y^2  = 1  \}$, then

$$
H(x,y) \equiv 0
$$

so $C$ is an invariant set.

But I am not really sure how to proceed to show that there exists no periodic orbits. Any hints will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Working on the point $(1,0)$, which lives on the invariant circle, you can see that the vector field vanishes. Therefore it is an equilibrium point. This implies that you can not have a periodic orbit on that circle.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly shown that the unit circle is invariant.

To show that it contains no periodic orbits, consider the equilibrium points of the system.

Comment: Do you mean "linearization" at each equilibrium point of the system?

Comment: I mean just find out *where* the equilibrium points are, and then consider what a periodic orbit inside the unit circle would look like.